# How do I resolve this "ORA-01109: database not open" error?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, database-administration

I'm trying to create my own database using SQLPlus. So first I log into it as admin:

```
sqlplus sys/sys_password as sysdba
```

And then I try to create a new user, called sqlzoo :

```
CREATE USER sqlzoo IDENTIFIED BY sqlzoo 
DEFAULT TABLESPACE tbs_perm_01sqlzoo 
TEMPORARY TABLESPACE tbs_perm_01sqlzoo 
QUOTA 20M ON tbs_perm_01sqlzoo;
```

This gives me the following error :

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01109: database not open
```

Why is it giving me such an error?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As the error states - the database is not open - it was previously shut down, and someone left it in the middle of the startup process. They may either be intentional, or unintentional (i.e., it was supposed to be open, but failed to do so).

Assuming that's nothing wrong with the database itself, you could open it with a simple statement:(Since the question is asked specifically in the context of SQLPlus, kindly remember to put a statement terminator(Semicolon) at the end mandatorily, otherwise, it will result in an error.)

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

Comment: Thanks !! For some reason, when I entered that command it tells me "Oracle not available" .. not sure

Comment: I think I should avoid using `sysdba` user?

Comment: please note that without the semicolon (;) at the end of the statement this will not work (at least from inside the SqlPlus)

Comment: Oracle. Where "STARTUP" doesn't "start up" a database and you're expected to know to do this as well...

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error

Answer (score 31):

I got a same problem. Below is how I solved the problem. I am working on an oracle database 12c pluggable database(pdb) on a windows 10.

-- using sqlplus to login as sysdba from a terminal; Below is an example:

> sqlplus sys/@orclpdb as sysdba

-- First check your database status;

> SQL> select name, open_mode from v$pdbs;

-- It shows the database is mounted in my case. If yours is not mounted, you should mount the database first.

-- Next open the database for read/write

> SQL> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE OPEN; (or ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE YOURDATABASENAME OPEN;)

-- Check the status again.

> SQL> select name, open_mode from v$pdbs;

-- Now your dababase should be open for read/write and you should be able to create schemas, etc.

Answer (score 7):

**If you are using 19c then just follow the following steps**

1. Login with sys user.
2. alter the session to the pluggable database with the following command.
3. **SQL>alter session set container=orclpdb;**
4. Next startup the database.
5. **SQL>startup**
   After that database will not show the above error.

Answer (score 6):

> alter pluggable database orclpdb open;`

worked for me.

`orclpdb` is the name of pluggable database which may be different based on the individual.

Answer (score 3):

```
I was facing some problem from SQL PLUS Command Promt.

So I resolve this issue from windows CMD ,I follow such steps--->

1: open CMD (Windows)

2: type show pdbs;

   now u have to unmount the data base which is mounted

3: type alter pluggable database database_Name open;

4: type show pdbs;(for cross check)
```

It works for me

Comment: Thanks a lot
Your solution solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

have you tried **SQL> alter database open;** ? after first login?

Comment: Hmm, I do this code, it tells me "Oracle not available" ??

Comment: if not available how you can login? check the database and listener services and try again

Comment: I think because I log in using :  `sqlplus sys/sys_password as sysdba` -  i think i should use normal user?

Comment: SYS has all privileges, you're wellcome

Comment: Hmm, that's what I thought. So something is really strange here, I will look into

Comment: If you're the DBA, just run SHUTDOWN, and then STARTUP, and report us what he replies.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error

Answer (score 1):

If your database is down then during login as SYSDBA you can assume this. While login command will be executed like sqlplus sys/sys_password as sysdba that time you will get "connected to idle instance" reply from database. This message indicates your database is down. You should need to check first alert.log file about why database is down. If you found it was downed normally then you can issue "startup" command for starting database and after that execute your create user command. If you found database is having issue like missing datafile or something else then you need to recover database first and open database for executing your create user command.

"alter database open" command only accepted by database while it is on Mount stage. If database is down then it won't accept "alter database open" command.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem takes me here. 
After all, I found that link, it's good for me.

[Source link](https://learn-oracle-database.blogspot.com/2016/04/validateconnames-pdbseed-is-not-open.html)

CHECK THE STATUS OF PLUGGABLE DATABASE.

> SQL> STARTUP; ORACLE instance started.
>
> Total System Global Area  788529152 bytes Fixed Size      2929352
>   bytes Variable Size    541068600 bytes Database Buffers   239075328
>   bytes Redo Buffers      5455872 bytes Database mounted. Database
>   opened. SQL> select name,open_mode from v$pdbs;
>
> NAME          OPEN_MODE
>   ------------------------------ ---------- PDB$SEED         MOUNTED PDBORCL          MOUNTED PDBORCL2         MOUNTED PDBORCL1
>   MOUNTED
>
> WE NEED TO START PDB$SEED PLUGGABLE DATABASE in UPGRADE STATE FOR THAT
>
> SQL> SHUTDOWN IMMEDIATE;
>
> Database closed. Database dismounted. ORACLE instance shut down.
>
> SQL> STARTUP UPGRADE;
>
> ORACLE instance started.
>
> Total System Global Area  788529152 bytes Fixed Size      2929352
>   bytes Variable Size    541068600 bytes Database Buffers   239075328
>   bytes Redo Buffers      5455872 bytes Database mounted. Database
>   opened.
>
> SQL> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL OPEN UPGRADE; Pluggable database
>   altered.
>
> SQL> select name,open_mode from v$pdbs;
>
> NAME          OPEN_MODE
>   ------------------------------ ---------- PDB$SEED         MIGRATE PDBORCL          MIGRATE PDBORCL2         MIGRATE PDBORCL1
>   MIGRATE

Answer (score 1):

As the error states - the database is not open - it was previously shut down, and someone left it in the middle of the startup process. They may either be intentional, or unintentional (i.e., it was supposed to be open, but failed to do so).

Assuming that's nothing wrong with the database itself, you could open it with a simple statement. (Since the question is asked specifically in the context of SQLPlus, kindly remember to put a statement terminator(Semicolon) at the end mandatorily, otherwise, it will result in an error. The semicolon character is a statement terminator. It is a part of the ANSI SQL-92 standard.)

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error

Answer (score 1):

1. Open SQLPLUS and login with sys as sysdba.
2. After that run **alter pluggable database <<database_name>> open;**

This Worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

please run this script

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
```

Answer (score 0):

While working on SQL developer tool I received the error while connecting to my pdb

> ORA-01109 database not open

I followed these steps to solve this issue:

- Logged in as a sys user
- `ALTER DATABASE OPEN` throws an error:- **ORA-01531: a database already open by the instance**
- changed container to pdb1:-  `ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=pdb1`

Problem Solved!

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error for Spring boot, then check VM arguments whether you have provided correct database configurations or not.

Answer (score -1):

il faut faire

SQL> STARTUP FRORCE

Comment: Please reply in English. Also review your answer, its probably ```STARTUP FORCE```

Comment: please answr in english, it is against the site policy to answer in other languages